# Refreshing the page submit my form

Tags: html, forms, button, submit

I have this code:

```
<form method="post" action="profile.php?id=<?php echo $dnn['id']; ?>">
 <input type="hidden" value="<?=$dnn['Username'];?>" name="userid" />
 <input type="submit" value="Add as Friend" />
</form>
```

**edit**

```
if ($_POST)
{  
  $fid = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['userid']));
  $fid = mysql_real_escape_string($fid);
  include("base.php");
  mysql_query("INSERT into contacts (ID, Nom, IDcontact, Nomcontact) VALUES ('".$_SESSION ['id']."', '".$_SESSION['Username']."', '".$dnn['id']."', '$fid')");
}
?>
```

My problem is that if the user refresh the page (without clicking on «add as friend»), the «friend» is added! And me I want to make the user click the button to add the friend, not only by refreshing the page! Any idea on what is my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: doesn't make much sense. You mean if no activity and just page refresh action happens?

Comment: Yes! Only page refresh and the «friend» is added in the database!

Comment: You either have a ajax call firing or problems in the server side, imho.

Comment: I think the problem come form the part I just added in the edit...

Comment: yeah you should use instead something like `if(isset($_POST['userid']){`

Comment: are you sure you're not refreshing a page that was a previous form submit and resubmitting the form?

Comment: Yeah, I just found the problem, and it's exactly that!

Answer (score 1):

Use this code :

```
if(isset($_POST['userid'])) {

 $fid = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['userid']));
 $fid = mysql_real_escape_string($fid);
 include("base.php");
 mysql_query("INSERT into contacts (ID, Nom, IDcontact, Nomcontact) VALUES ('".$_SESSION ['id']."', '".$_SESSION['Username']."', '".$dnn['id']."', '$fid')");


}
```

Hope it works ...